# Why doesn't $('document').load() fire?

Tags: jquery

I replaced .ready() with .load():

```
$('document').load(function(){
  alert('test');
});
```

but nothing happens.  Go back to ready() and it works fine.  There isn't anything in the document.  It's just a blank HTML file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Only haters out there... a simple comment that there is a typo would be more nicly than devote and silly comments!!! OP has 11k reps and surely know how to code.

Comment: .ready() works with or without the quotes.  What's your deal?

Comment: @4thSpace: No; `.ready()` ignores elements entirely.  You can't just add quotes in random places an expect things to work.

Comment: I vote to reopen, it's not only the typo, `document` can't handle `load` event. I believe a correct answer addressing this can help other users

Comment: @ClaudioRedi, yea i realized that after i answered with the `document` typo, so i've already updated my answer.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling sometimes you don't see the typo and end up in a (for you) real problem. When someone points this out, you might realize that you failed for a moment. And that's human! Still no need to be rude... In germany we have a proverb: (translated) "There havent been no master that fell down from heaven until now"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(document)` not `$('document')` when selecting the document because there is no `<document>` element.

Additionally, `document` doesn't fire a load event. `window` fires the load event. You should be using `$(window).load(...)`.

The reason why `$('document').ready()` works is because `.ready()` doesn't actually use any selector context, and the API should have always been `$.ready(...)`. Avoid `$(document).ready()` and stick with the aliasing shorthand version:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    ...
});
```

Also, be aware that binding to `document.ready` *after* the document is ready will still fire the callback. Binding to `window.onload` *after* the window has loaded **will not fire the callback**.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert('document selector works');
});

$('document').ready(function () {
  alert('invalid selector works');
});

$().ready(function () {
  alert('no selector works');
});

$(window).load(function () {
  alert('window load works!');
  
  $(window).load(function () {
    alert("load has already fired, this doesn't work");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think so.  Quotes don't matter.

Comment: @4thSpace 'check here amateur' . Really? at least respect his reputation.

Comment: @4thSpace, [if you're going to use jsfiddle, don't forget to check your fiddle settings](http://i.imgur.com/fFTb04S.png).

Answer (score 4):

In an HTML page there is no `document` **tag**, you must call it as

```
$(document).load(function() { ... });
```

However, **the document element has no load event**, if you want your function to trigger at full loading of the page, you should use

```
$(window).load(function() { ... }); // use "window" instead of "document"
```

instead, while if you need it to fire when DOM is ready, just use

```
$(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Quotes make no difference.

Comment: Yes they do: here on FF, if I open firebug, `$('document')` is `Object[]` while `$(document)` is `Object[Document why-doesnt-document-load-fire]`, and OP is calling `load()` method, which requires a valid selector.

Comment: @4thSpace I realized just now that **you** are the OP, sorry for that, however I think my answer still is correct :)